# Отслеживание ввода и показ сообщения

Tags: javascript, jquery, форма

Есть форма на сайте, если пользователь не ввел в течение времени туда никакие данные, показать ему сообщение. Как это реализовать на JS?

Comment: какие поля в форме: `input`, `textarea`, `radio`, `checkbox`? Уточните.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с расширенной проверкой и логикой:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var oWrap = document.querySelector('.wrap');
  var tCheck;

  function fCheck() {
    let nCheck = 0;
    oWrap.querySelectorAll('form>*').forEach(function(item) {
      if (item.value) { nCheck++; }
    });

    if (nCheck == 0) {
      alert('Заполните форму');
    } else if (nCheck == 3) {
      alert('Вы можете отправить данные'); return
    } else {
      alert('Не все поля заполнены');
    }
    tCheck = null;
    tCheck = setTimeout(fCheck, 5000);
  }

  oWrap.addEventListener('input', function() {
    if (tCheck) {
      clearTimeout(tCheck);
      tCheck = null;
      tCheck = setTimeout(fCheck, 5000);
    }
  });
  
  tCheck = setTimeout(fCheck, 5000);
}
```

```css
.wrap {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

form>* {
  margin: 4px 0;
  display: block;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 1.3em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px dotted #090;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <form>
    Name:<input>
    Age:<input>
    Message:<textarea></textarea>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
      if ($('#input').val().length === 0) {
         alert('Введите что нить')
      }
    },3000)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='input' type="text">
```